# Why does scanner.hasNextInt() method need a letter to start processing numbers?

Tags: java, integer, java.util.scanner, delimiter

I am trying to get some integer inputs from user by using scanner.hasNextInt() method. It works just fine but I need to type a letter to let the program know that I'm done entering integers while I want the console to know that after I press the enter key after a single line.

For example, I type
(1
2
3
y
enter)
and the program works just fine but if I type
(1
2
3
enter
enter)
nothing happens, even if I keep pressing the enter key. This is the related part of my code, if you need to take a look at it.

```
public class Main {
    static LinkedList linkedList =new LinkedList();

    public static void main(String [] args){
       System.out.println("enter integer numbers");
       Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
       while (scanner.hasNextInt()){
          linkedList.append(scanner.nextInt());
       }
       print();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. There is no method called `append(...)` for `LinkedList`. Did you mean `add(...)`?

Comment: It's just part of my code, try it with another method to see the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Three steps to understand it.

1. `Scanner` uses a delimiter to break the input into tokens, the default delimiter is `\p{javaWhitespace}+`. Try

   ```
   Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
   System.out.println(scanner.delimiter());
   ```
2. `\p{javaWhitespace}` is equivalent to `java.lang.Character.isWhitespace()`, so `\p{javaWhitespace}+` will matches multiple characters which `isWhitespace`.
3. A line break produced by key `enter` is a white space. When you enter multiple `enter`s, they will be recognized as a delimiter, not a token.

You can use s single white space, so it will take the second `enter` as token:

```
scanner.useDelimiter("\\p{javaWhitespace}");
```